# What does it mean when "aclocal cannot open VERSION"

Tags: configure, autoconf, m4

Is this the correct forum?  I am running ./bootstrap for a program called Qucs and it complains about VERSION

```
Running aclocal...
Running automake...
Running autoconf...
bootstrapping /home/lasse/Downloads/qucs-0.0.20/qucs-core
bootstrapping the qucs-core sources...
Creating aclocal.m4... sh: 1: cannot open VERSION: No such file
sh: 1: cannot open VERSION: No such file
done.
Creating config.h.in... sh: 1: cannot open VERSION: No such file
done.
Libtoolizing... libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
done.
Creating Makefile.in(s)... sh: 1: cannot open VERSION: No such file
done.
Creating configure... done
bootstrapping /home/lasse/Downloads/qucs-0.0.20/qucs
Creating aclocal.m4... sh: 1: cannot open VERSION: No such file
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
sh: 1: cannot open VERSION: No such file
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
done.
Creating config.h.in... sh: 1: cannot open VERSION: No such file
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
done.
Running libtoolize
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
Running automake... sh: 1: cannot open VERSION: No such file
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
done.
Running autoconf... done.
bootstrapping /home/lasse/Downloads/qucs-0.0.20/qucs-doc
Creating aclocal.m4... sh: 1: cannot open VERSION: No such file
configure.ac:15: error: AC_INIT should be called with package and version arguments
/usr/share/aclocal-1.15/init.m4:29: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE is expanded from...
configure.ac:15: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
done.
Creating Makefile.in(s)... sh: 1: cannot open VERSION: No such file
configure.ac:15: error: AC_INIT should be called with package and version arguments
aclocal.m4:172: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE is expanded from...
configure.ac:15: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
automake: error: autoconf failed with exit status: 1
done.
Creating configure... sh: 1: cannot open VERSION: No such file
configure.ac:15: error: AC_INIT should be called with package and version arguments
aclocal.m4:172: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE is expanded from...
configure.ac:15: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
done.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the suspicion that you cloned the git repo, e.g. `git clone https://github.com/Qucs/qucs.git`, but did not initialize the submodules.

That would be consistent with the VERSION files it can and cannot find.

So, in the directory, run `git submodule update --init`, and try again.

Comment: Thank you. It now concludes that admsXml is not working:```Checking if /usr/local/bin/admsXml is working...  no 
configure: error: need admsXml, but not found. consider --with-mkadms=<alternative admsXml>``` but the command ```which admsXml``` really gives 
/usr/local/bin/admsXml
which was what I provided to ./configure

Comment: well, it seems to need admsXml (which I don't know), which it does not seem to find. Did you install it? I don't know which operating system / distribution you're on, otherwise one could help you find the package containing it (serious question: what about installing qucs from packages?).

Comment: I think the problem was that I downloaded the tarball of admsXML over a low-bandwidth line which corrupted it instead of cloning git, then also not exporting enviromentvariables. Also doing the mistake of simultaneously working on git cloned Qucs and the tarball downloaded Qucs then not following instructions as you detected.

Comment: this all sounds very much like you should be installing Qucs from your package manager and not build it from source. Qucs hasn't moved much in the last years, you're really not winning anything building it from source.